# Massive template cache cleaning tasks always get stuck

Tags: cache, caching

We have a site where we use lots of `{% cache %}` tags.

Now we almost constantly have a "cleaning template cache" task running, and they often get stuck.

Manual DB intervention and resetting the stuck task to status `pending`, will sometimes make it move again.

I've tried the various solution here, but nothing helps: [DeleteStaleTemplateCaches job getting stuck](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8237/deletestaletemplatecaches-job-getting-stuck)

Also - there are no error entries in craft.log or phperrors.log when it gets stuck.

Looking at the `craft_templatecaches` table I find lots of duplicate looking entries:

```
select id,locale, cacheKey, expiryDate, path from craft_templatecaches;

...
| 685607 | nb     | zDzBdD8bc1y4pf9Sx2HFyL3i24YypSp2sAq5 | 2015-09-08 08:23:21 | site:kompetansetilbud/ny-i-hr-rollen-i-trondheim-10013                                   |
| 685610 | nb     | TMz4eh7FPiINSUixwkpXb0SlkHnZ3b5TSgXm | 2015-09-08 08:23:22 | site:kompetansetilbud/ny-i-hr-rollen-i-trondheim-10013                                   |
| 685611 | nb     | HgLIHHgf56nM1ggOdTmaLlaylu5JeOeM1dNm | 2015-09-08 08:23:23 | site:kompetansetilbud/ny-i-hr-rollen-i-trondheim-10013                                   |
| 685612 | nb     | SLHUKfUz2fF5Jmpy0kWPpvMxFBHH8PvlVJEt | 2015-09-08 08:23:25 | site:kompetansetilbud/ny-i-hr-rollen-i-trondheim-10013                                   |
| 685614 | nb     | oEU6fe1tGc7MdI8WSQIXsf2wZZd9qmXG8P9H | 2015-09-08 08:23:26 | site:kompetansetilbud/ny-i-hr-rollen-i-trondheim-10013                                   |
...
```

Is this normal?

Anything else I can do to debug why the task gets stuck?

---

Update:

Using keyed and global caching reduced the size of the `craft_templatecaches` table from ~20k rows to ~300. However, this did not stop the task getting stuck.

Comment: You might want to use a key on those cache tags. It looks like it's always creating new caches: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/7096/cache-always-creates-new-cache-data-never-uses-existing-cached-data

Comment: Also take a look at http://buildwithcraft.com/help/stuck-tasks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long 'Deleting stale template caches'](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/long-deleting-stale-template-caches)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Fred, using the `{% cache globally using key craft.request.path %}` trick from https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/8335/342 gets rid of almost all duplicates!

But for the last few I notice that the duplicates all expire within seconds of each other, maybe this is an instance of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_stampede ?

I.e. several clients request the pages "simultaneously" and the page is rendered several times, and each version is cached?